# Return true per item if list1 contains part of any string from list2

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, contains

If a string(or part of a string) from list1 is the same as a string in list2 the string needs to be added to a listbox.

I now have:

```
            int g = 0;

            while (g < musthaves.Count())
            {
                if (list1.Contains(list2[g].ToString()))
                {
                    listBox14.Items.Add("Found: " + list2[g].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox14.Items.Add("Not found: " + list2[g].ToString());
                }
                g++;
            }
```

The list are:

list1:
testcase scan document
testcase upload document
testcase delete document

list2:
upload document
scan document
indicate inconsistency

So the listbox should contain:

Found: upload document
Found: scan document
Not found: indicate inconsistency

But my results are Not found for every string.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking only that full string is one of the item in the another list, but your requirement is

> If a string (**or part of a string**) from list1 is the same as a string in list2

So you need to check every phrase in `list2` if phrase **contains** one of the expected phrases from the `list1` (uhh, I would suggest to use more descriptive names for variables - will simplify conversations :))

```
foreach (var requiredPhrase in list1)
{
    if (list2.Any(phrase => phrase.Contains(requiredPhrase))
    {
        // Found
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it too except the lists are the wrong way round based on the example in the question

Answer (score 1):

> But my results are Not found for every string.

Because `List.Contains` checks for an exact match of the item. E.g. you are checking if there is a string `"upload document"` in the `list1`, and that is not true.

What you need is `Enumerable.Any` to check if any element in sequence matches condition. And `String.Contains` to check if string from second list is a substring of string from `list1`:

```
if (list1.Any(l1 => l1.Contains(list2[g])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should help you.

```
list2.Where(x=>list1.Any(c=>c.Contains(x)));
```

The above query would iterate over each element in `list2` and retrieve those which is a *substring* of any of items in `list1`